Playwright Parallel Test Execusion
I have a playwright test suite with around 300+ test cases. Given below is the structure of it

section 01

test 01
* 01_test.spec.ts
* 02_test.spec.ts
* 03_test.spec.ts
* 04_test.spec.ts
test 02
* 05_test.spec.ts
* 06_test.spec.ts
* 07_test.spec.ts
test 03
* 08_test.spec.ts
* 09_test.spec.ts


section 02

test 01
* 10_test.spec.ts
* 11_test.spec.ts
* 12_test.spec.ts
test 02
* 13_test.spec.ts
test 03
* 14_test.spec.ts
* 15_test.spec.ts



to run the section 02 we must run section 01. section 01 has the configuration parts that need for the section 02.
To run this whole test suite it takes more than 2 hours now and i want to reduce this time by running these tests parallelly. I can run the section 01 parallelly without any issue. But my section 02 contains some test files that cannot be run parallelly (they have some date changes and data cleaning function)
So what i want to do is run the tests that can be run in parallel parallelly and others in serial mode.

run section 01 parallelly
run section 02 parallelly (tests that are okay to run parallelly and ignore that can't)
run those ignored tests in serial mode
how can i do this.
I tried this below approach

{
            name: "setup env",
            testMatch: /global\.setup\.ts/,
            use: {
                channel: "chrome"
            }
        },
{
            name: "parallel tests",
            testDir: "./tests",
            fullyParallel: true,
            use: {
                ...devices["Desktop Chrome"],
                channel: "chrome",
                ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
                acceptDownloads: true,
                launchOptions: {
                    slowMo: 0,
                },
            },
            grepInvert: /.*(04_test.spec.ts, 06_test.spec.ts, 10_test.spec.ts  ).*/,
            dependencies: [ "setup env" ],
        },
        {
            name: "serial-tests",
            testDir: "./tests",
            fullyParallel: false,
            use: {
                ...devices["Desktop Chrome"],
                channel: "chrome",
                ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
                acceptDownloads: true,
                launchOptions: {
                    slowMo: 0,
                },
            },
            grepInvert: /.*(04_test.spec.ts, 06_test.spec.ts, 10_test.spec.ts  ).*/,
            dependencies: [ "setup env" ],
        },

this does not give me the expected behavior. i have defined 4 workers above in the config file and when i run the tests like this until the very end there are 4 workers. but what i want is to change the workers to 1 when "parallel tests" project is done.
Given below are two pictures of how my tests run right now and what kind of behavior i want to achieve.



This question is similar to: Playwright: Running certain files parallel and others serial in. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Inside my all test files i'm using
test.describe.configure({ mode: 'seial' })
Tests that are written inside one file (eg: 01_test.spec.ts, 02_test.spec.ts, 03_test.spec.ts, 04_test.spec.ts) cannot run parallelly. But most of these files can run parallelly. So i was trying to run whole test suite parallelly and ignore few test files (that cannot run parallely) and run them serial with one worker after parallel running is done. But i couldn't achieve that behavior by changing my playwright config file yet

Did you try the suggestions from the link? Which ones did you try and how did they go for you?

My each test file contain only one describe block and that has multiple tests and I'm already using test.describe.configure({ mode: 'seial' }) in my all describe blocks. And in the playwright config I tried defining separate projects for parallel and serial and adding dependencies to them kind of things. But nothing worked. If I add my parallel test project as a dependency to my serial project, then all my tests inside serial project get skipped. Even if I did not add dependency it still runs parallelly with other tests and failing.

'seial' is a typo. Please share your actual code as a [mcve]--it doesn't need to be extensive, just a few simple tests and files enough to illustrate the problem.

It's a best practice to make each test self-contained and independent. Is there no way to kill the dependency between your tests?

set   fullyParallel: false in playwright config and dont use multiple projects. use a single one. and run the tests, When fullParallel is set to False, Playwright will run all the spec files in Parallel and all the tests inside the each spec file will run serially.
